# Unable to uninstall jruby (windows): jvm could not start

Tags: java, jvm, jruby

I've got this version on jruby in Windows 10:

> jruby 1.7.13 (1.9.3p392) 2014-06-24 43f133c on Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.7.0_80-b15 [Windows 8-x86]

and when I try to uninstall it from Control Panel I keep on getting the error:

> The JVM could not be started. The maximum heap size (-Xmx) might be too large or an antivirus or firewall tool could block the execution.

Any idea what I could try to delete this installation? I tried reinstalling the .exe file, to see if it had an option to remove/repair, but nothing, it just reinstalled it and I still have the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No commands seem to work for me, at the end I had to do it through a specific software design for this kind of issues: http://www.perfectuninstaller.com/

Answer (score 0):

check your environment variables ... you might have `JRUBY_OPTS` or `JAVA_OPTS` set.

unset those or adjust the **-Xmx** setting accordingly.

Comment: I had JRUBY_OPTS set to -J-Xmx128m. I've now removed it, tried to uninstall it again, but getting the same error...

For now, I had to create another new partition and start from scratch, but I'd like to have this sorted in the original partition as I had more things installed...

Do you know anything else that I could check and try?